# Dropwizard 0.8.0: serve static assets from /

Tags: path, assets, dropwizard

I want my server to serve the static html files from `/`. Furthermore, css and js files should be served from `/css` respectively, `/js`. All json data should be accessible at `/api`.

However, I get a 404 for `http://localhost:8080/` or any other path.

I use the following setting in the configuration file:

```
server:
  type: simple
  rootPath: /api/*
```

The application.initialize method looks like this:

```java
@Override
public void initialize(io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap<MyConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets/css", "/css", null, "css"));
    bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets/js", "/js", null, "js"));
    bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets/pages", "/", "index.html", "html"));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just had to work through a similar problem ([The documentation](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.8.0/docs/manual/configuration.html) isn't the clearest, although with hindsight I guess most of the information is there somewhere), which I've resolved by setting both the `applicationContextPath` and the `rootPath` in my application config:

```
server:
  type: simple
  rootPath: /api/*
  applicationContextPath: /
```

The [default value for `applicationContextPath` is "`/application`" in a simple server](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/v0.8.0/dropwizard-core/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/server/SimpleServerFactory.java#L60), so your complete root-path would have been "`/application/api/*`". If you don't need to use the *simple* server, you could alternatively use the *default* server, which has the applicationContextPath set to "`/`" by default:

```
server:
  rootPath: /api/*
```

Comment: Agreed, no clear documentation, for such a powerful tool as Dropwizard, thank you!

Comment: brilliant, this answer made by day